# Automatically parse text from a website dialog box

Tags: python, python-requests

[This website](https://indexes.morningstar.com/indexdata) contains a column *Index Constituents*. Clicking any of the sheet symbols in that column, opens up a modal box.

How can I open such a modal box and retrieve its content as text, using python code?

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://indexes.morningstar.com/indexdata")
print(r.text)
```

Only reads the host website, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello **user1934212**,

this 'Dialog Box' is a '[Bootstrap Vue Modal](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/)' which you can parse pretty easy.

This little code snippet below is parsing the '*Index Constituents*' from the first entry (Morningstar Australia Moat Focus GR AUD) in the table.

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://indexes.morningstar.com/getIndex/holdings/0P0001A41J")
data = r.json()
print(data)
```

Basicly you can iterate over the '*Index Constituents*' column and use each id of the button to get the content you want.

```
https://indexes.morningstar.com/getIndex/holdings/HERE_ID
```

If you have more questions about this feel free to ask, I'll answer later.

[Screenshot of the ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azoPv.png)